# ruby on rails virus using server for ddos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, ddos

How to clean ruby on rails app if I've been infected with some virus that uses my DigitalOcean server to send outgoing traffic? Probably for ddos attacks.

I just made new droplet with all security updates, but when I run bunndle install it started to spit large traffic.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/denial_of_service/

Comment: @DineshSaini can't understand hot this reading will help me.